# why does ddply gives NA values when changing the order of functions?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm using `ddply` and when changing the order of functions, sometimes, some are `NA`. here is a reproducible example (I kept all strings as in my original df except for the values in the right 2 columns):

demo df:

```
test_ddplyr=data.frame(genotype=c(rep("dr5_dmso", 5), rep("184_2_bc1_2_2", 5)), 
  root=c("r1s6", "r2s4", "r3s2", "r4s3", "r5s1", "r2s4", "r3s2", "r4s3", "r1s2", 
  "r5s4"), area=c(1:10), intensity=seq(100, 1000, 100))
```

proper ddply output:

```
ok_ddply=ddply(test_ddplyr, .(genotype), summarise, se_area=sd(area)/sqrt(length(area)), 
  se_intensity=sd(intensity)/sqrt(length(intensity)), area=mean(area), 
  intensity=mean(intensity))
```

improper ddply output with `se_area` column is NA:

```
bad_ddply=ddply(test_ddplyr, .(genotype), summarise, 
  se_intensity=sd(intensity)/sqrt(length(intensity)), area=mean(area),    
  intensity=mean(intensity), se_area=sd(area)/sqrt(length(area)))
```

any suggestions?
Thanks a lot,
Guy

Comment: The parameters are processed in the order they appear. When you do `area=mean(area)`, you are redefining `area` for all the subsequent parameters. Don't change values that you need later, or just give them different names rather than the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sure ddply will only draw information (in this case the column names) from the data argument